# Java - Multithreading Issue with too many threads

Tags: java, multithreading

A 3rd party API which provides realtime stock data is creating a new thread for each price update of each scrip (section of code as below).

```
byte[] data = new byte[byteLength];
System.arraycopy(byteArray.toByteArray(), index, data, 0, data.length);
new Thread(new BrokerAPI.parseData(data)).start();
```

This creates about 250,000+ threads each day (in 4 - 5 hours), which even to a newbie like me looks like a bad design. My program starts throwing NullPointerException after about 2 hours although the prices are getting updated. I suspect the issue is due to the high number of threads getting generated.

The total number of scrips which I need to monitor is about 120, so I am looking at a way of having a max of 120 threads, where-in each price update is written to the specific thread.

I refer to the solution (Producer/Consumer pattern) provided in [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048385/deterministic-assignment-of-tasks-to-threads-using-executorservice) which I think should address this need. Request guidance on how I can translate that into code as am new to this. Alternatively if there is any other way of achieving this with minimal number of threads would be glad.

Comment: well if you can edit the source code, replace new Thread construct with delegation to thread pool of desired size. This API is CPU bound so you should not create more threads than there are cores.

Comment: Do you have permission and ability to  edit this 3rd party API? If not, there's nothing that can be done. If you can, I'd suggest reading up about `Executors` and `ExecutorService`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NullPointerExceptions are not direct result of too many threads, something else breaks and causes them (likely memory related).

You create a managed thread pool somewhere

```
private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

and let it decide what threads to (re-)use instead of creating your own threads:

```
byte[] data = new byte[byteLength];
System.arraycopy(byteArray.toByteArray(), index, data, 0, data.length);
executorService.execute(new BrokerAPI.parseData(data))
```

Comment: thanks. I will make the changes as advised by you & test it tomorrow during the live data streaming session.

Comment: That definitely helped reduce the number of threads getting created. But I still get a NullPointerException when sorting a TableView, will ask that as a separate question. Thanks