# Java - TableView Sorting results in NullPointerException after a certain duration

Tags: java, sorting, nullpointerexception, tableview

*Context:* 
The program sorts realtime stock data displayed in a TableView.

*Issue:*
I get a NullPointerException as shown in the stack trace below.  The null pointer starts after about 1 hour of execution & continues. I am perplexed because the sorting does take place as desired despite the error. Hope the issue I face is clear & seek guidance. This question is linked to the other question I posted [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791861/java-multithreading-issue-with-too-many-threads)

```
//Added If condition to prevent NullPointer, but it still occurs
if (listTableView.size() > 0) {
    sortTable(observableList);
}

//Added Try-Catch, but it shows NullPointer instead of message in catch block
private void sortTable(ObservableList<stockData> observableList) {
    try {
        observableList.sort((s1, s2) -> {
            if (s1.getPrice() < s2.getPrice()) {
                return 1;
            } else if (s1.getPrice() > s2.getPrice()) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-245" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.sort(ObservableListWrapper.java:226)
at controller.ControllerTrade.sortTable(ControllerTrade.java:511)
at controller.ControllerTrade.updateTableList(ControllerTrade.java:492)
at controller.ControllerTrade.updateTabs(ControllerTrade.java:430)
at controller.ControllerTrade.update(ControllerTrade.java:403)
at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:159)
at com.sharekhan.core.BrokerAPI$BroadcastSubject.newData(BrokerAPI.java:107)
at com.sharekhan.core.BrokerAPI$parseData.run(BrokerAPI.java:279)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: If you are adding to the list in another thread while sorting you will get strange events like this.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon anyway out? I have 2 lists, 1 is the feedList which receives the data from the 3rd party API & the other is the displayList. The 2 lists are bound. The feedList is continuously being updated & sorted. The code performs the feedList update first & as a last step does the sort.

Comment: If the list is small enough you could sort a **copy** of it for display. If not you must implement some kind of locking mechanism. A `ReadWriteLock` would probably be appropriate.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon i enclosed the sorting within writeLock, but doesn't help.
readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();

sortTable(observableList);

readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();

Comment: That is good. Now take a write lock whenever you are writing to it too.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon no success still. I wrapped the code with lock & unlock individually where ever it is updating the lists. The strange thing is the issue starts after about an hour or two after the program starts execution.